# Use angular.element to get scope object by $ID

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to pass data from an angular app to scripts that run outside of angular because I do not have access to editing the code of the angular app.

Using Angular Batarang and NG-Inspector extensions for Chrome, I can see the JSON object I need to pull from, but I am at a loss of how to start.

For instance, in Angular Batarang, the object looks like:

```
$id=5
name: "listing"
keys:
   0: "alpha"
   1: "beta"
alpha:
   user: "test"
   userID: "12345"
beta: 
   address: "555 Elm St"
   phone: 555.555.5555
```

My initial thought was I could grab it using `angular.element` but I haven't had any successes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can determine which element that scope is bound to, select the element, and grab it's scope via [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). Assume this scope is attached to element `<div id="stuff"></div>`, observe the following example, specifically, the call to `.scope()`

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" id="stuff"></div>

<button onclick="getStuff()">get stuff</button>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.inside = { 'name': 'guy', 'idk': 'blah' }
});

var getStuff = function() {
    var outside = angular.element(document.getElementById('stuff')).scope();
    console.log(outside.inside) // retrieved "outside" of AngularJS
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/06Ldnys8/) - demo

---

Update

Per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods), debug mode must be enabled.

> scope() - retrieves the scope of the current element or its parent. Requires Debug Data to be enabled.

It's enabled by default, and [disabling it](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) will cause issue here

Comment: You are awesome.  That worked perfectly...my problem was that there were custom elements, so instead of getElementById, I went to querySelectorAll and found the element that had the scope object I was looking for.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: I believe the scope() method doesn't work, when running Angular in production mode. This is a bit of a pitfall because it works well, up until it's deployed.

Comment: @djabraham production mode? Can you explain a little more what you mean?

Comment: I wouldn't make an app dependent on scope(), because it's not there when debug data is disabled. You can enable debug data on a deployed app in real-time, in order to debug issues. But leaving debug data on by default would hurt performance, so apps are typically deployed without this feature enabled. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production

Comment: I don't see anything in there about `.scope()` not working. If anything, it reminds you that it *does* work > These scope references can then be accessed via element.scope()

Comment: I simply would like to change the color of an HTML text element (that I have assigned an ID to) from an ng-click="???" - It works correctly from <script>getElement etc.</script> - but I am not able to trigger a color change via ng-click. Nor am I able to trigger the working <script> from ng-click...