# Calling a function from Document.ready using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a main.html which is in the controller scope of encMain. The page has some few buttons

```
main.html
--------
<div ng-app="enc" ng-controller="encMain">
<input type="button" value="Click A" ng-click="A()" ></>
<input type="button" value="Click B" ng-click="B()"></>
<input type="button" value="Click C" ng-click="B()"></> 
</div>


main.js
-----
var app = angular.module('enc', []);
app.controller('encMain', function ($scope) {

$scope.A = function() { alert('A function is invoked') }

$scope.B = function() { alert('B function is invoked') }

$scope.C = function() { alert('C function is invokedl') }



}
```

I dont have any issue in calling the function from the html Page on the click of the button.
However for sample explanation for the functionality i require i need to call the below funcion when the document is ready (DOM is available).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  --- updateA function will be invoked from some X page. 
  window.updateA = function(){
   $scope.A - function A to be called here. this is inside in the scope of encMain.
 }

 function UpdateBandC(){
   $scope.B - function B to be called here. this is inside in the scope of encMain 
   $scope.C - function C to be called here. this is inside in the scope of encMain.
  } 

 UpdateBandC() - Call to the above function UpdateBandC.
}
```

Case 1. Let assume i have a page 'Y' and i would invoke a call to the below 'updateA' function.
I dont have any problem in invoke of the function. However once the function is invoked internally 
i need to call the 'A' function which is in the scope of encMain. Problem is i dont know how the call the function 'A' from document.ready or how can i get the reference of scope and how can i give the reference to make a call to the function A.

Case 2. UpdateBandC() to be invoked once the DOM is ready which internally needs to call the '
B' and 'C' function which is in the scope of encMain. Problem is i dont know how to do the call 
of function B and C when document is ready or how can i get the reference of scope and how can i 
give the reference to make a call to the function A and B.

Thanks. Please ignore typo errors. 
Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610912/use-angular-element-to-get-scope-object-by-id

Comment: thanks. it worked. But i would like to know if there could be a better approach